# Outer join behaving unexpectedly when join clause contains condition

Tags: mysql, left-join, aggregate-functions

A core feature of a `left outer join` query is that it preserves all rows of the left table. But I have a situation where (in MySQL) this appears not to work; namely, when using a `group by` clause on the right table and adding a condition to the `on` part of the join clause.

This query works as expected:

```
select CUSTOMERS.*, sum(ORDERS.ORDERTOTAL) as TURNOVER from CUSTOMERS
left outer join ORDERS on (ORDERS.CUSTID=CUSTOMERS.CUSTID)
group by ORDERS.CUSTID
order by CUSTOMERS.CUSTID;
```

I get a row for every row in the CUSTOMERS table (with `TURNOVER` being NULL if there are no ORDERS rows.)

However, with this slightly modified query...

```
select CUSTOMERS.*, sum(ORDERS.ORDERTOTAL) as TURNOVER from CUSTOMERS
left outer join ORDERS on (ORDERS.CUSTID=CUSTOMERS.CUSTID) and (ORDERS.ORDERDATE > '2018-01-01')
group by ORDERS.CUSTID
order by CUSTOMERS.CUSTID;
```

... the result is much different: Some rows from the CUSTOMERS table do not have a corresponding result row. The interesting thing is that this appears to be not *directly* related to whether or not there are ORDERS rows that satisfy the `ORDERDATE > ...` condition. Even when there are no rows in ORDERS that satisfy this at all, I get at least one (in my small test database) result row. But it looks like if a custimer has at least one matching ORDERS row that satisfied the condition, then that customer is present in the result set.

So what can I do to get the desired result - *preserving* the CUSTOMERS rows, getting one row for every customer, regardless whether it has ORDERS rows that satisfy the condition or not?

Bonus points for anybody who can point out where my misunderstanding of outer join queries lies. :)

***Updated to add (2019-03-18):***

To clarify... Table CUSTOMERS:

```
CUSTID : NAME
-----------------------
1      : John Doe
2      : Frank Duffmann
3      : Maggie Mae
```

Table ORDERS:

```
ORDERID : CUSTID : ORDERDATE  : ORDERTOTAL
-------------------------------------------
1       : 1      : 2018-01-01 : 150.00
2       : 3      : 2019-01-01 : 77.77
3       : 3      : 2019-01-01 : 88.88
4       : 1      : 2017-01-01 : 100.00
```

Expected result: A result set with three rows, one for each CUSTOMER.

Comment: Your condition is killing NULLs that OUTER JOIN creates.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: NULL is not more than '2018-01-01'.  You may want to try `ORDERS.ORDERDATE IS NULL OR ORDERS.ORDERDATE > '2018-01-01'`.

Comment: No change when I try this. There are no actual NULL dates in the table.

Comment: OK. Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I'm confused why orderdate is part of the join condition.  Shouldn't it be a WHERE clause instead?  It has nothing to do with the actual join between the tables.

Comment: No. It is a condition for the JOIN, so that it filters the right table. If it were in the WHERE clause, it would cause records in the left (preserved) table to be suppressed, which is exactly what I don't want.